# group seperators

Tags: php, regex

I have these strings:

```
something && otherthing
something || otherthing && something
```

How can I write the regex that matches above multi line strings individually?

I have tried:

[`\w+\s+(&&|\|\|)\s+\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/cOsZOY/1)

What is the right approach for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do it like this and repeat the pattern for `\w+ (?:\|\||&&)` one or more times and then end with `\w+`:

[`(?:\w+ (?:\|\||&&) )+\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/jXWLAS/2/)

That would match:

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\w+` Match one or more word characters followed by a whitespace
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\|\||&&` Match || or &&
  - `)` Close non capturing group and match whitespace
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat one or more times
- `\w+` Match one or more whitespaces

**Edit**: As per comment added anchors to match from the beginning to the end of the line:

[`^(?:\w+ (?:\|\||&&) )+\w+$`](https://regex101.com/r/jXWLAS/3)

Comment: That works great :) But note that I had to insert `^` and `$` to make it work ;)

Comment: @stack I have updated my answer with the anchors `^` and `$`.

Comment: Yeah, I am waiting for the time when I can accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This will match it:

`(?:\w+ ?(?:&&|\|\|)? ?)+`